# Unable to see Sort options for some columns among list of columns of a List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I want the Sort option to be enabled for all the columns in a list. But i cannot see the ribbon(which gives sort ascending/descending option) beside some columns. 
Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: What types are the columns that you can't sort with?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the field types can be used for sorting but not all the types.

For example you can't sort with a column of type Multiple line of text.

Comment: I am trying to sort "Choice type", but cannot see the option.

Comment: If the choice field allows multiple selections then it's not sortable. If it doesn't allow multiple selections  then it should be sortable.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. Didn't know that before.

Answer (score 0):

In a SharePoint 2019, I have a list that has fields that I am not able to select.

1. The items to select are based on a field choice type selected.
2. This field is not set to multiple selection field and actually none of the fields of the list are set to multiple selection.
3. The field provides no access to selecting the field by type (choice) to choose to display only.
4. How can I enable the field to be sorted or select the field type to display? Is there a feature or type of field that I need to select to make this work?